# Studies of sequences of the type $\{1\}, \{1,2,1\}, \{1,2,3,4,3,2,1\}, \cdots$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory

I am studying a stochastic method, and when I do calculations I get sequences of the type $\{1\}, \{1,2,1\},\{1,2,3,4,3,2,1\}, \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1\}, \cdots$ appearing everywhere.

This led me to want to learn more about them. I reckon they probably show up a lot in mathematics. Do they have a name, such that I can look them up and learn more about them?

I was unsure what tags to give this question. If you are more knowledgeable than me, feel free to come in and edit them.

Comment: The sequence without the brackets (i.e. $1,1,2,1,1,2,3,2,1,\dots$) appears as [OEIS/A004737](http://oeis.org/A004737).

Comment: This a concatenation of palindromic sequences.

Comment: Are you asking about [unimodal sequences?](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnimodalSequence.html)

Comment: Yes, some special kind of unimodel sequences it seems

Comment: The last one isn't unimodal. Typo?

Comment: Fixed typo, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if this works for you Marius:

https://oeis.org/A028356/internal

Comment: It's all interesting. Have you got something which goes: {1,1,2,1,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1...?